# The Present Perfect Progressive with the modal verb "must."

Tags: grammar

I do not know how would it be correctly to use the Modal Verb Must in the meaning of supposition in the  Present Perfect Progressive?

For example:
1) He must be sitting there already two hours.
2) He must have been sitting there alredy two hours.

The Present Perfect Progressive expresses that the action began before the moment of speaking but it's still in progress.

3) Is it correct to say alredy for two hours?

Please could you point out other my mistakes if i did in the questuion?

Comment: Once you introduce ***must***, the "Present Perfect Progressive" doesn't necessarily imply the action is still in progress. *He must have been beating his wife for decades before she died in 1980.* Also note that *...already sitting there [for] two hours* and *...sitting there [for] two hours already* are both idiomatic, but your version isn't.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: 3) No, it's "for two hours already."

Comment: Preposition "for" may be omitted in a such case or not?

Comment: More likely is _He must have been sitting_ (/hi'məstəbɪn'sɪʔṇ/) _there for two hours now._ One can also say _by now_, but that implies some previous mention of duration in the discourse.

Answer (score 1):

These versions seem normal to me (native English speaker):

He must have been sitting there for two hours already

He must already have been sitting there for two hours

or:
He must have been sitting there for two hours by now

The position of "already " is important to sound idiomatic. The version in the question sounds "wrong " to me mainly for this reason, not because of the verb forms used.